# How safe is overloading new array operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, memory-alignment

Assuming I'm using a struct to be allocated on heap and used as

- new [] and delete[]
- shared_ptr(new [])

then can I simply overload its new array operator and don't touch any delete [] operator

```
struct  alignas(256)  MyStruct
{
    Item i1,i2;
    void * operator new[](unsigned long int size)
    {
        return aligned_alloc(256,size);
    }

    void * operator new (unsigned long int size)
    {
        return aligned_alloc(256,size);
    }
};
```

and consider it done without any leaks?

GCC 6.3 and c++0x.

Comment: Why do you think that you don't need to supply `delete` and `delete[]` too?

Comment: Isn't it calling free()? Is free() enough for all kinds of _alloc_ commands?

Comment: What do you mean by `it`? Who is supposed to call `free()`?

Comment: Then non-overloaded deletion does not work on overloaded new?

Comment: In the general case, of course not. Why would it work? You can do **anything** which allocates memory in operator new. How would operator delete know about this, if you don't overload it?

Comment: So there is a magic delete inside of delete, I need to overload it with my simple free() then.

Comment: There can be magic inside `delete`. Example: Getting the memory for `new` from statically allocated blocks isn't all that uncommon. You don't want to call `free` on that, program will go boom. Instead you want to put the block back in your own freelist for re-use.

Comment: It might work in your case. **If** `aligned_alloc()` memory can be freed with `free()`, and if the original `operator delete` just calls `free()`, then it will work. But relying on this is a **very** bad habit. Don't do it. Supply `operator delete` properly.

Comment: Then after supplying both `delete[]` and `delete` overloads, I'm okay right? Also it doesn't say anything about `new` gives `size` as 1(number of single struct) or number of bytes called by default parameter (of struct size). I assume `new[]`  gives number of structs as parameter(not total bytes)

Comment: Yes, supply both. new's parameter is number of bytes, so you don't have to multiply it with `sizeof()`. Just a comment: if you don't supply `operator delete`, problem won't be memleak, but instead a possible crash. As the original `operator delete` doesn't know, how to handle the pointer.

Comment: Recommend making sure that you are not obligated to throw an exception if  `aligned_alloc` returns NULL. I strongly suspect that you are, but I've never dug into the underbelly of `aligned_alloc`

Comment: @user4581301 maybe I check against NULL until its not NULL? Maybe after N trials, it kills process.

Comment: In my worldview `new` should know nothing. It either works or it doesn't and makes sure the caller knows which. Retry behaviour I would leave up to the caller. The caller is almost certainly in a better position to decide whether continuing to try to allocate is possible or even desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The truth is, there is no guarantee on how your standard library implements those `operator new()` functions, whatsoever. Your standard implementation might just call through to `malloc()` and `free()`, but it's not required to do so. It may just as well use the `sbreak()` syscall itself to back the memory objects it manages. Or it could use the `mmap()` syscall.

**Either of these three is perfectly possible, and incompatible with the other two implementations. And, just as bad, your standard `operator delete()` implementation may consult some hidden data fields in front of the pointer that you pass into it to perform its internal bookkeeping.** If the pointer that is passed into your standard `operator delete()` is not actually a pointer that was returned by the matching `operator new()`, you have undefined behavior. And the probability of something really bad happening is very high.

There is really no way around it: If you supply `operator new()`, you must also supply `operator delete()`. Otherwise, all hell may break loose.

Answer (score 1):

If you overload `new` on a object, you should overload `delete` as well. Likewise, if you overload `new[]`, you should overload `delete[]`. This is because the object will use the default `delete`, which may lead to a crash, depending on how you've messed with `new`.

Depending on your compiler, `delete` may call `free()` anyway, but you should get into the habit of overloading both `new` and `delete`, especially if you change how your object gets allocated.

Comment: "since `delete` calls `free()` anyway" there's no guarantee for that.